# Generate random numbers in range without repetition

Tags: python, function, random

I'm creating a trivia game and need to call 10 questions (functions) in a random order. I could simply generate a random integer 1-10 and use `if` statements to call each function, but I need to make sure that no questions are called more than once, so I need to generate random numbers without repetition.

```
def Trivia_Snap():
    question_1()
    question_2()
    question_3()
    question_4()
    question_5()
    question_6()
    question_7()
    question_8()
    question_9()
    question_10()
```

Comment: Why don't you put the functions in a list then `random.shuffle` it? Then you can just write `for func in funcs: func()` rather than ten nearly-identical lines. It's likely there are broader fixes to make - consider taking your code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com **once you have it working**.

Comment: I wish the people who downvoted your question could present their reason for doing so...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this has been asked 1000 times and is easy to Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the calls to the functions in a list

```
l = [question_1, question_2...]
```

Then select from that list randomly without replacment

```
import random
rand_l = random.sample(l, len(l))

for f in rand_l:
    f()
```

**EDIT:** per comments below you can also use `shuffle`

```
random.shuffle(l)
for f in l:
    f()
```

Comment: This is clearly the best approach, but note that the OP wants to call *all* of them

Comment: @jonrsharpe this will... I am saying I want `len(l)` samples from the list, so I will get all of them

Comment: My point is that you can just `shuffle`, rather than making a `sample` of all of them.

Comment: Question has been modified to show `shuffle` as alternative

Comment: You'll need to refactor slightly; `shuffle` is **in-place**

Comment: Unless he needs the original order for something else, it's fine to be in place

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import random
```

create a list of numbers

```
>>> l = range(0,11)
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

...and shuffle them in place with [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

```
>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> l
[5, 7, 4, 2, 1, 8, 6, 10, 9, 0, 3]
>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> l
[1, 5, 9, 4, 10, 6, 2, 7, 0, 3, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

qlist = [i for i in range(0,10)]
random.shuffle(qlist)

for q in qlist:
    print q
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a list of questions:

```
questions = ['Q: foo?', 'Q: bar?', Q: 'baz?']
```

With the following function you can present all these questions for an user to answer. Everytime you call the function, the questions will be presented in a different order. It will return a list of tuples in which each tuple represents the number of the question answered, as enumerated from the original question list, and the answer to the question:

```
from random import shuffle

def trivia_snap(questions):
    q = list(enumerate(questions))
    shuffle(q)
    answers = []
    for question in q:
        answers.append((question[0], input(question[1] + " Answer: ")))
    return sorted(answers)


>>> trivia_snap(questions)
>>> Q: foo? Answer: "Homer"
>>> Q: baz? Answer: "Marge"
>>> Q: bar? Answer: "Lisa"
>>> [(0, "Homer"), (1, "Lisa"), (2, "Marge"), ]
```

Hope it helps!